# Unable to validate the loader of the web page using Selinium webdriver with groovy script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, webdriverwait

In Jmeter selinium webdriver - trying to validate the loader and once loader completes web page will be displayed for confirming I need to print the result as "success"

This is my code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//*[@class=\"spinner-border uxf-spinner-border-lg\"]")));
```

Border class is `@class=\"spinner-border uxf-spinner-border-lg\`
Getting error as:

```
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: wait for class:
```

Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: wait for class:
```

...implies that that the `wait` object wasn't initialized before being used.

---

### Solution

The [**WebDriverWait**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class have been redefined as:

```
WebDriverWait​(WebDriver driver, java.time.Duration timeout)
```

So your effective line of code will be:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='spinner-border uxf-spinner-border-lg']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This  is because `wait` object is not defined, you need to explicitly [declare](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,java.time.Duration)) it beforehand

Something like:

```
def wait = new org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, java.time.Duration.ofSeconds(5))
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)